# Perl Apache Issue

Tags: apache, perl

I cant seem to even fix this issue, I've tried so many things and nothing will work...

I'm basically doing this for a friend of mine, I've setup apache properly in his ubuntu server but whenever I try to access the register file in `usr/lib/cgi-bin`, it keeps giving me a 500 internal server error.

This is the site configuration file(000-default.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
 AllowOverride None
 Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews      +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 </Directory>

# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is the register file:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use CGI;
  use Method::Signatures;
  use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
  use Drivers::MySQL;
  use feature qw(say);

  print header();

  my %arrConfig = (
          dbHost => '127.0.0.1',
          dbName => 'Luna',
          dbUser => 'root',
          dbPass => 'password123'
  );

  my $objHtml = CGI->new;
  my $objMysql = MySQL->new;

  $objMysql->createMysql($arrConfig{dbHost}, $arrConfig{dbName}, $arrConfig{dbUser}, $arrConfig{dbPass});

  if ($objHtml->param) {
     parseResults(\%arrConfig, $objMysql, $objHtml);
  } else {
    displayPage(\%arrConfig, $objHtml);
  }

  method parseResults(\%arrConfig, $objMysql, $objHtml) {
   my $strName = $objHtml->param('username');
   my $strPass = $objHtml->param('password');
   my $strPassTwo = $objHtml->param('passwordtwo');
   my $intColour = $objHtml->param('colour');
   my $strIP = $objHtml->remote_host;

   my $intNameCount = $objMysql->countRows("SELECT `username` FROM users WHERE `username` = '$strName'");
   my $intIPCount = $objMysql->countRows("SELECT `ipAddr` FROM users WHERE `ipAddr` = '$strIP'");

   if ($intIPCount > 2) {
       error('You Can Only Own Two Accounts Per IP Address');
   } elsif (!$strName && !$strPass && !$strPassTwo && !$intColour) {
       error('You Did Not Complete All The Fields! Please Try Again');
   } elsif ($strName !~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) {
       error('Username Is Invalid');
   } elsif ($strName > 12 && $strName < 3) {
       error('Username Contains Too Many Or Less Characters');
   } elsif ($intNameCount > 0) {
       error('Username Already Exists');
   } elsif (length($strPass) > 20 && length($strPass) <= 5) {
       error('Password Contains Too Many Or Less Characters');
   } elsif ($strPass ne $strPassTwo) {
       error('Password Does Not Match');
   } elsif ($strPass !~ /^(?=.{5,10}$)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*[@#*=])(?!.*\s+)/) {
       error('Password Requires One Uppercase, Lowercase, Integer And Special Character');
   } elsif (!int($intColour) && $intColour > 15 && $intColour < 0) {
       error('Invalid Colour');
   }

   my $strHash = md5_hex($strPass);

   my $intID = $objMysql->insertData('users', ['nickname', 'username', 'password', 'colour', 'active', 'ipAddr', 'stamps'], [$strName, $strName, $strHash, $intColour, 1, $strIP, '31|7|33|8|32|35|34|36|290|358|448']);

   $objMysql->insertData('igloos', ['ID', 'username'], [$intID, $strName]);
   $objMysql->insertData('postcards', ['recepient', 'mailerName', 'mailerID', 'notes', 'postcardType', 'timestamp'], [$intID, 'Luna', 0, 'Welcome To Luna!', 125, time]);

   say $objHtml->h1('You have successfully registered');
   say $objHtml->p($objHtml->u('Your account details:'));
   say 'Username: ' . $objHtml->b($strName);
   say 'Password: ' . $objHtml->b($strPass);
   say 'ID: ' . $objHtml->b($intID);
  }

  method displayPage(\%arrConfig, $objHtml) {       
   say $objHtml->start_html(-title => 'Luna', -bgcolor => 'white');
   say $objHtml->start_center;
   say $objHtml->start_form(-name => 'main', -method => 'POST');
   say $objHtml->start_table;

   my %arrColours = (
                  1 => 'Blue', 
                  2 => 'Green',
                  3 => 'Pink',
                  4 => 'Black',
                  5 => 'Red',
                  6 => 'Orange',
                  7 => 'Yellow', 
                  8 => 'Dark Purple',
                  9 => 'Brown',
                  10 => 'Peach',
                  11 => 'Dark Green', 
                  12 => 'Light Blue',
                  13 => 'Light Green',
                  14 => 'Gray', 
                  15 => 'Aqua'
   );

   say $objHtml->Tr($objHtml->td('Username:'), $objHtml->td($objHtml->textfield(-placeholder => 'Enter your name', -type => 'text', -name => 'username', -maxlength => 12)));
   say $objHtml->Tr($objHtml->td('Password:'), $objHtml->td($objHtml->textfield(-placeholder => 'Enter your password', -type => 'password', -name => 'password', -maxlength => 20)));
   say $objHtml->Tr($objHtml->td('Repeat Password:'), $objHtml->td($objHtml->textfield(-placeholder => 'Enter your password again', -type => 'password', -name => 'passwordtwo', -maxlength => 20)));
   say $objHtml->Tr($objHtml->td('Colour:'), $objHtml->td($objHtml->popup_menu(-name   => 'colour', -values => [sort keys %arrColours], -labels => \%arrColours)));

   say $objHtml->Tr($objHtml->td($objHtml->submit(-value => 'Submit')));
   say $objHtml->end_table;
   say $objHtml->end_form;
   say $objHtml->end_center;
   say $objHtml->end_html;
 }

 method error($strError) {
   my $strBoldError = $objHtml->b($strError);
   my $strErrorStatement = $objHtml->p($strBoldError);
   say $strErrorStatement;
   exit;
 }
```

I've changed the file permission to 755 and  checked the syntax and its all fine.

Is there something I'm not seeing? All the error log says is "End of script output before headers".

Error log:

Error log as per request:

```
[Thu Dec 24 02:56:38.929902 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15417:tid 140140605220736] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 24 02:56:38.929965 2015] [core:notice] [pid 15417:tid 140140605220736] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 24 02:59:21.946307 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15417:tid 140140605220736] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 24 02:59:22.986351 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15569:tid 139751035283328] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 24 02:59:22.986419 2015] [core:notice] [pid 15569:tid 139751035283328] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 24 03:06:59.763950 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 15574:tid 139750820263680] [client 106.208.29.16:26368] AH01265: attempt to invoke directory as script: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
[Thu Dec 24 03:43:57.494621 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 15569:tid 139751035283328] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 24 03:43:58.542633 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18173:tid 140578810890112] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 24 03:43:58.542713 2015] [core:notice] [pid 18173:tid 140578810890112] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 24 03:44:24.357114 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18177:tid 140578633279232] [client 106.208.31.1:1569] AH01264: script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/egister
[Thu Dec 24 03:44:43.672738 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18235:tid 140578810890112] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 03:44:43.672938 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18177:tid 140578599708416] [client 106.208.31.1:1591] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Drivers/MySQL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Drivers::MySQL module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
[Thu Dec 24 03:46:39.938441 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18177:tid 140578507388672] [client 106.208.31.1:1635] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Drivers/MySQL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Drivers::MySQL module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
[Thu Dec 24 03:46:44.769191 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18178:tid 140578448639744] [client 106.208.31.1:1645] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
[Thu Dec 24 03:54:02.681970 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18178:tid 140578557744896] [client 106.208.31.1:1836] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
[Thu Dec 24 03:54:13.856406 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18177:tid 140578574530304] [client 106.208.31.1:1856] End of script output before headers: index.pl
[Thu Dec 24 03:59:20.898641 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18178:tid 140578566137600] [client 106.208.31.1:1984] AH01264: script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl
[Thu Dec 24 04:00:38.302010 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 19584:tid 140578810890112] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 04:00:38.302221 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18178:tid 140578507388672] [client 106.208.31.1:2004] End of script output before headers: register.pl
[Thu Dec 24 04:01:01.468669 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 19585:tid 140578810890112] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 04:01:01.468947 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18177:tid 140578448639744] [client 106.208.31.1:2017] End of script output before headers: register.pl
[Thu Dec 24 04:14:40.401399 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 19929:tid 140578810890112] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 04:14:40.401631 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18177:tid 140578473817856] [client 106.208.88.238:21256] End of script output before headers: register.pl
[Thu Dec 24 04:15:11.473083 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 19932:tid 140578810890112] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 04:15:11.473309 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18177:tid 140578448639744] [client 106.208.88.238:21259] End of script output before headers: register.pl
[Thu Dec 24 04:15:29.327062 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 19933:tid 140578810890112] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 04:15:29.327299 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18178:tid 140578515781376] [client 106.208.88.238:21261] End of script output before headers: register.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
[Thu Dec 24 04:26:55.088334 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18177:tid 140578507388672] [client 106.208.88.238:21429] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Global symbol "$objHtml" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$arrConfig" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 10.
Global symbol "$objMysql" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 10.
Global symbol "$objCaptcha" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 10.
Global symbol "$objHtml" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 10.
Global symbol "$arrConfig" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 12.
Global symbol "$objCaptcha" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 12.
Global symbol "$objHtml" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 12.
Global symbol "$arrConfig" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 15.
Global symbol "$objMysql" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 15.
Global symbol "$objCaptcha" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 15.
Global symbol "$objHtml" requires explicit package name at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 15.
syntax error at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl line 15, near ") {"
/var/www/cgi-bin/register/register.pl has too many errors.
[Thu Dec 24 04:27:05.714035 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 18177:tid 140578498995968] [client 106.208.88.238:21431] End of script output before headers: register.pl
[Thu Dec 24 04:40:42.364455 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18173:tid 140578810890112] AH00494: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Thu Dec 24 04:40:42.416326 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18173:tid 140578810890112] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 24 04:40:42.416346 2015] [core:notice] [pid 18173:tid 140578810890112] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
[Thu Dec 24 04:41:59.664833 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21137:tid 140578591315712] [client 106.208.88.238:21717] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
[Thu Dec 24 04:42:02.220502 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21138:tid 140578549352192] [client 106.208.88.238:21718] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
[Thu Dec 24 04:44:49.927410 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21138:tid 140578566137600] [client 106.208.88.238:21721] End of script output before headers: index.pl
[Thu Dec 24 04:54:15.130660 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 18173:tid 140578810890112] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 24 04:54:16.170870 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 21771:tid 139956861183872] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 24 04:54:16.170948 2015] [core:notice] [pid 21771:tid 139956861183872] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 24 05:02:30.290833 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 22814:tid 139956861183872] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 05:02:30.291121 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21775:tid 139956550829824] [client 106.208.88.238:21885] End of script output before headers: index.pl
[Thu Dec 24 05:02:40.239370 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 22815:tid 139956861183872] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 05:02:40.239626 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956626364160] [client 106.208.88.238:21886] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Drivers/MySQL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Drivers::MySQL module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
[Thu Dec 24 05:17:15.648064 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21775:tid 139956592793344] [client 106.208.200.98:26239] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
[Thu Dec 24 05:22:21.030515 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956500473600] [client 106.208.200.98:26268] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
[Thu Dec 24 05:22:29.155624 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21775:tid 139956643149568] [client 106.208.200.98:26270] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
[Thu Dec 24 05:26:59.929825 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21775:tid 139956601186048] [client 106.208.200.98:26304] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
[Thu Dec 24 05:51:24.665808 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956525651712] [client 106.208.200.98:26704] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
[Thu Dec 24 05:53:44.378650 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956592793344] [client 106.208.200.98:26740] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
[Thu Dec 24 05:53:47.788531 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956584400640] [client 106.208.200.98:26741] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
[Thu Dec 24 06:01:51.924274 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21775:tid 139956508866304] [client 106.208.200.98:26845] End of script output before headers: index.pl
Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 9.
[Thu Dec 24 06:14:41.811638 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956525651712] [client 106.208.8.87:37448] End of script output before headers: index.pl
[Thu Dec 24 06:20:34.074040 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 25176:tid 139956861183872] (8)Exec format error: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 06:20:34.074226 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956753745664] [client 106.208.8.87:37575] End of script output before headers: index.pl
[Thu Dec 24 06:20:36.556068 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 25177:tid 139956861183872] (8)Exec format error: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 06:20:36.556361 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956668327680] [client 106.208.8.87:37576] End of script output before headers: index.pl
[Thu Dec 24 06:22:25.511908 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 25178:tid 139956861183872] (8)Exec format error: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 06:22:25.512111 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956659934976] [client 106.208.8.87:37584] End of script output before headers: index.pl
[Thu Dec 24 06:22:41.714336 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 25179:tid 139956861183872] (8)Exec format error: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/Drivers/MySQL.pm' failed
[Thu Dec 24 06:22:41.714585 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956651542272] [client 106.208.8.87:37585] End of script output before headers: MySQL.pm
[Thu Dec 24 06:29:55.940279 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 25401:tid 139956861183872] (8)Exec format error: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/Drivers/MySQL.pm' failed
[Thu Dec 24 06:29:55.940485 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956626364160] [client 106.208.8.87:37713] End of script output before headers: MySQL.pm
[Thu Dec 24 06:29:58.537769 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 25402:tid 139956861183872] (8)Exec format error: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/Drivers/MySQL.pm' failed
[Thu Dec 24 06:29:58.538022 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956609578752] [client 106.208.8.87:37714] End of script output before headers: MySQL.pm
[Thu Dec 24 06:30:07.320777 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 25403:tid 139956861183872] (8)Exec format error: AH01241: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl' failed
[Thu Dec 24 06:30:07.320967 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 21776:tid 139956601186048] [client 106.208.8.87:37715] End of script output before headers: index.pl
```

Comment: The usual reason for a 500 error is that your script died.  There is almost always an indication of why it died in the apache error log, so look there.

Comment: Put `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` at the top. Then if the script runs at all you should get some meaningful information in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Check your perl version by typing perl -v in the terminal. If it is 5.20< , you should install perl module CGI.pm since it has been removed from the core perl bundle.
In the top portion of your perl code, you had written as

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Method::Signatures;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
use Drivers::MySQL;
use feature qw(say);

print header(); #########

my %arrConfig = (
        dbHost => '127.0.0.1',
        dbName => 'Luna',
        dbUser => 'root',
        dbPass => 'password123'
);

my $objHtml = CGI->new; #########
my $objMysql = MySQL->new;
```

As far as I know, it should be written as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Method::Signatures;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
use Drivers::MySQL;
use feature qw(say);

my $objHtml = CGI->new; #########

print $objHtml->header(); #########

my %arrConfig = (
        dbHost => '127.0.0.1',
        dbName => 'Luna',
        dbUser => 'root',
        dbPass => 'password123'
);
my $objMysql = MySQL->new;
```

Hope this will work fine...
Please run following command to know if there any other syntax error in the perl using following command perl -c . It will help you identify any missing modules in the server.

Comment: Tried this, still showing an Internal Server Error..I've used so many ubuntu servers before...this is the first one I've landed with such kind of an issue...

Comment: added it, sorry about the fornat :s im on a phone

Comment: It's alright. based on the log, you missed to install perl modules like Drivers::MySQL. Please run following command to know if there any other syntax error in the perl using following command perl -c <file_name.ext>. It will help you identify any missing modules in the server.

Comment: Drivers::MySQL is a small wrapper I wrote, other than that everything else I've installed. Upon checking the syntax, its says "Ok" and no errors. I checked the permissions and tried changing them to 705, 755, 711 but nothing worked sadly.

Comment: I'm sorry. There is nothing else I can do without getting hands on the machine. Hope you are perl programmer. check the error log. hope you will get something from it.

Comment: "If it is 5.20>= you should install perl module CGI.pm since it has been removed from the core perl bundle" Pedantically, CGI.pm was removed from the Perl core in Perl 5.22.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the important parts of your error log:

> Can't locate Drivers/MySQL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   Drivers::MySQL module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl
>   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5
>   /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line
>   11. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.

And:

> Can't locate Data/Alias.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   Data::Alias module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl
>   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5
>   /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Method/Signatures.pm line 980.
>   Compilation failed in require at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl
>   line 11. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11

There's are two modules called Drivers::MySQL and Data::Alias missing. By missing I mean one of these two situations is true:

1. The module isn't installed on this server.
2. The module is installed on this server, but it isn't in one of the directories where Perl looks for libraries.

The error message gives you the list of directories where Perl looks for libraries (it's in the variable called `@INC`).

You have two options for fixing it. Either move the local copy of the module to one of the directories in `@INC` or (probably better) adjust `@INC` to include the directory where your module is. This is usually done with a `use lib` statement. For example:

```
use lib ('/path/to/the/directory/that/includes/Drivers',
         '/path/to/the/directory/that/includes/Data');
```

Answer (score 0):

From your log:

> Can't locate Drivers/MySQL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Drivers::MySQL module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/cgi-bin/register/index.pl line 11.

You need to install the Drivers::MySQL module.

Hopefully `cpanm Drivers::MySQL` will do that, but [cpan](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) has more instructions.

You have a similar issue with `Data::Alias`.